# SQL select with "IN" subquery returns no records if the sub-query contains NULL

Tags: sql, null, left-join, in-subquery

I came across this interesting behavior. I see left-join is the way to go, but would still like to have this cleared. Is it a bug or behavior by-design? Any explanations?

When I select records from left table, where a value is not present in the result of a subquery on the right table, the expected "missing" record is not returned if the subquery result has nulls. I expected the two ways to write this query to be equivalent.

Thanks!

```
declare @left table  (id int not null primary key identity(1,1), ref int null)
declare @right table (id int not null primary key identity(1,1), ref int null)

insert @left (ref) values (1)
insert @left (ref) values (2)

insert @right (ref) values (1)
insert @right (ref) values (null)

print 'unexpected empty resultset:'
select * from @left
where ref not in (select ref from @right)

print 'expected result - ref 2:'
select * from @left
where ref not in (select ref from @right where ref is not null)

print 'expected result - ref 2:'
select l.* from @left l
  left join @right r on r.ref = l.ref
where r.id is null

print @@version
```

gives:

```
(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)
unexpected empty resultset:
id          ref
----------- -----------

(0 row(s) affected)

expected result - ref 2:
id          ref
----------- -----------
2           2

(1 row(s) affected)

expected result - ref 2:
id          ref
----------- -----------
2           2

(1 row(s) affected)

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64) 
    Apr  2 2010 15:48:46 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.0 <X64> (Build 6002: Service Pack 2) (Hypervisor)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is by design. If the match fails and the set contains NULL the result is NULL, as specified by the SQL standard.

```
'1' IN ('1', '3') => true
'2' IN ('1', '3') => false
'1' IN ('1', NULL) => true
'2' IN ('1', NULL) => NULL

'1' NOT IN ('1', '3') => false
'2' NOT IN ('1', '3') => true
'1' NOT IN ('1', NULL) => false
'2' NOT IN ('1', NULL) => NULL
```

---

Informally, the logic behind this is that NULL can be thought of as an unknown value. For example here it doesn't matter what the unknown value is - '1' is clearly in the set, so the result is true.

```
'1' IN ('1', NULL) => true
```

In the following example we can't be sure that '2' is in the set, but since we don't know all the values we also can't be sure that it *isn't* in the set. So the result is NULL.

```
'2' IN ('1', NULL) => NULL
```

Another way of looking at it is by rewriting `x NOT IN (Y, Z)` as `X <> Y AND X <> Z`. Then you can use the rules of [three-valued logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29#Three-valued_logic_.283VL.29):

```
true AND NULL => NULL
false AND NULL => false
```

Comment: Design ? Isn't the word consent?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is how it was designed. There are also many other considerations between doing a `LEFT JOIN` or a `NOT IN`. You should see this [link](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/) to have a very good explanation of this behavior.

Comment: I liked a lot the article you're linking to. Easy to follow and explains very well difference between NOT IN/NOT EXISTS/LEFT JOIN. Thanks! Now if the author could expand it to include the inverse cases (IN/EXISTS/EXCEPT (SQL 2005+) ), it'd be really great.

Comment: @Joe Pineda Yeah, its a great article. I wish I had more merit than just found it, though....

Comment: Hi, thanks for the article link, that was very helpful. Though I'm choosing Mark's answer as it's got in-line explanation. Robert

Answer (score 0):

That is the way the ANSI committee thinks have to be done.

You can precede your queries with

```
set ansi_defaults OFF
```

and you get the result that you expect.

Since SQL-Server 7.0 Microsoft is rather strict about following ansi standards.

**EDIT:**

Don't fight against the defaults. You will give up in the end.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of the behavior is explained by Mark. It can be resolved in more than one way, - LEFT JOIN, Filtering NULL values from inner query by filtering out them from where clause OR from select clause, using a co-related sub-query - to name a few.

Following three short posts is a case study on the same subject:- [NOT IN Subquery return zero rows -Issue](http://www.tectalks.com/527/subquery-with-not-in-predicate-return-zero-rows/), [NOT IN Subquery return zero rows -Root Cause](http://www.tectalks.com/557/not-in-subquery-return-zero-rows/), [NOT IN Subquery return zero rows -Workarounds](http://www.tectalks.com/598/not-in-subquery-alternatives/)