# Why does this PostgreSQL query result in 0 results even though I know there are

Tags: sql, postgresql

There are 2 tables in my system: journal and journal_contribution. Both have a field uuid as primary key and the journal_contribution contains the field journal_uuid to link it to a journal. The other fields are not of importance. The journal table has 461283 records and the journal_contribution 336136 records.

I want to determine how many journals I have that do not have a journal_contribution referring to them.

My first idea was the following query

```
select count(*)
from journal 
where uuid not in 
(select journal_uuid as uuid
from journal_contribution)
```

I know this is not very performant but I was surprised that after 2 minutes I got 0 as result.
Even more so that if I run the same query without the 'not' I do get as result 124121. If I subtract this from the total number of journals I would have expected the original result to be 337162.

When I change the code to the following more performant version I do get the right result but I want to understand the 0 in the first place. Can somebody explain this to me?

```
select count(*)
from journal 
where not exists
(select 1  
from journal_contribution jc
where jc.journal_uuid = journal.uuid)
```

These queries were done in pgAdmin 4.21 running PostgreSQL 11

Comment: Have you checked that NULL-values are not present in the subquery?

Comment: There are NULL-values in the subquery. How does that change anything?

Comment: You are right: If I add 'is not null' to the subquery it does return the correct result. Why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL NOT IN not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231712/sql-not-in-not-working)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I strongly, strongly discourage you from using `not in` with subqueries.  The reason is simple:  `NULL` values are not handled intuitively.

As you have observed, `NOT IN` filters out *all* rows if *any* of the rows returned by the subquery are `NULL`.

There is a simple alternative:  `not exists`:

```
select count(*)
from journal j
where not exists (select 1
                  from journal_contribution jc
                  where jc.journal_uuid = j.uuid
                 );
```

In addition, this query can make use of an index on `journal_contribution(journal_uuid)`.  I am guessing that with such an index, this query will be rather speedy.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the subquery contained NULL values.

Changing the query to

```
select count(uuid)
from journal 
where uuid not in 
(select distinct journal_uuid as uuid
from journal_contribution
 where journal_uuid is not null)
```

gives the correct result

The reason why this gives the result it gives is answered in [SQL select with "IN" subquery returns no records if the sub-query contains NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539340/sql-select-with-in-subquery-returns-no-records-if-the-sub-query-contains-null)

The EXISTS operator has apparently no problem with NULL values

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the column "journal_uuid" is nullable in "journal_contribution" table. When trying to use the IN operator, NULL value will always return nothing. Just like to writing something like `WHERE id = NULL` will return nothing.
The other query is working because you're trying to compare uuid values from the "journal" table and if I'm not wrong it's a primary key and not nullable

Comment: Well the values compared are the same. It seems EXISTS does not have an issue with NULL values

Comment: in the first query, the sub query will return a set of values, one or more of the values will be null because journal_contribution.journal_uuid is nullable so the query will look something like
```
select count(*)
from journal 
where uuid not in (null, ...values)
```
which will always return nothing because the IN operator will compare each value with the "=" sign just like ```id = NULL``` will not work.
The second query works that way: the sub query will try to find a all rows wth the same uuid and if so the exists function will return true or false.